# Developing Apache module - error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘apr_socket_t {aka struct apr_socket_t}’

Tags: apache-modules

I'm trying to access the socket descriptor in apache module. Changed mod_example.c:

```
conn_rec *conn = r->connection;
struct apr_socket_t *csd = (struct apr_socket_t *)((core_net_rec *)conn->input_filters->ctx)->client_socket;
int sock_fd = csd->socketdes;
```

And there is an error: 
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct apr_socket_t’
         int sock_fd = csd->socketdes;

apr_network_io.h is in the include path.
Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the typesafe recipe for getting the native socket in a module:

```
apr_socket_t s = ap_get_conn_socket(r->connection);
int fd = 0;
apr_os_sock_get(&fd, s);
```